# What is the difference in the pivoting strategies between LAPACK's dpstrf and dpst2 and why?

Tags: linear-algebra, lapack

[dpstf](http://www.netlib.org/lapack/explore-html/da/dba/group__double_o_t_h_e_rcomputational_gae5d8ecd7fbd852fe3c3f71e08ec8332c.html#gae5d8ecd7fbd852fe3c3f71e08ec8332c) and [dpstrf](http://www.netlib.org/lapack/explore-html/da/dba/group__double_o_t_h_e_rcomputational_ga31cdc13a7f4ad687f4aefebff870e1cc.html#ga31cdc13a7f4ad687f4aefebff870e1cc) sometimes give different pivot results. Of course I can read the source code, but I don't get the idea from it. Since pivoting is for stability of the Cholesky decomposition, one of them is more stable. Which and why does the other exist?

Answer (score 2):

The difference is which BLAS level they are utilizing. TRF is BLAS3 and TF2 is BLAS2. BLAS level 3 routines, roughly speaking, optimized for computers with cache memory such that they can perform block calls. BLAS 2 is optimized for vector computers with possibly shared memory.

As you can see in [the code (line 209)](http://www.netlib.org/lapack/explore-html/da/dba/group__double_o_t_h_e_rcomputational_ga31cdc13a7f4ad687f4aefebff870e1cc.html#ga31cdc13a7f4ad687f4aefebff870e1cc), if the optimum block size turns out to be either larger than the matrix size(which implies the impossibility of blocked algorithm) or less than or equal to 1 then DPSTRF falls back to the unblocked version DPSTF2.